# calculating the number of months since given date in a new DataFrame column

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I'm having a pandas issue.

I have a dataframe that looks like the following:

```
name     date
Mark     2018-01-01
Anne     2018-01-01
Anne     2018-02-01
Anne     2018-04-01
Anne     2018-09-01
Anne     2019-01-01    
John     2018-02-01
John     2018-06-01
John     2019-02-01
Ethan    2018-03-01
```

And I need to compute an additional column, call it `months`, that contains the number of months between the first value in date column for a given same name. This is in order to calculate how many months have gone by since the first time a name appears in the DataFrame. The calculation must be done grouping by name, as I only want to know the number of months since the first appereance of the user in the rows where the user name appears, not for any other user name.

The expected output in this case would be:

```
name     date          months
Mark     2018-01-01    0
Anne     2018-01-01    0
Anne     2018-02-01    1
Anne     2018-04-01    3
Anne     2018-09-01    8
Anne     2019-01-01    12
John     2018-02-01    0
John     2018-06-01    4
John     2019-02-01    12
Ethan    2018-03-01    0
```

Any tips on what is the most efficient way of computing the `months` column will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe `df['months'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date']).groupby(df['name'], sort=False).diff().fillna(pd.Timedelta(0)) ` as a starting point... but then tweak for how to round as necessary...

Comment: The problem is it returns the result in days. How could I round it to months?

Comment: How would you want to define a month? Would `2018-01-01 -> 2018-01-31` be 0 months, but `2018-01-01 -> 2018-02-01` and `2018-01-01 -> 2018-02-28` would both be 1 month even though one is barely a month and the other is pretty much almost 2 months?

Comment: As you can see, in my data source I only have months by the first day of the month. This means, the day is always the first. Thus, if I have 2018-01-01 and 2018-02-01, I count it as a 1 month of difference.

Comment: Please if you could update your answer, the question will doesn’t have a correct answer. I really need to know it.

Comment: I haven't given you an answer... I just made a comment to get you started and clarify what it was you're after... it appears other *actual* answers solve your problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `GroupBy.transform` to get the lowest value as an equal length vector as our dataframe. Then subtract each `date` value with this vector and divide it by a `1 month timedelta`

```
mins = df.groupby('name')['date'].transform('min')

df['months'] = df['date'].sub(mins).div(pd.Timedelta(1, 'M')).round().astype(int)
```

**Output**

```
    name       date  months
0   Mark 2018-01-01       0
1   Anne 2018-01-01       0
2   Anne 2018-02-01       1
3   Anne 2018-04-01       3
4   Anne 2018-09-01       8
5   Anne 2019-01-01      12
6   John 2018-02-01       0
7   John 2018-06-01       4
8   John 2019-02-01      12
9  Ethan 2018-03-01       0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the dateutil package. By the way, according to your logic, shoud the month for the 4th row be 3 instead of 2?

```
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

df['month'] = df.apply(lambda x: relativedelta(x.date,df.loc[df.name==x['name']].date.min()).months, axis=1)

name        date        month
0   Mark    2018-01-01  0
1   Anne    2018-01-01  0
2   Anne    2018-02-01  1
3   Anne    2018-04-01  3
4   Anne    2018-09-01  8
5   John    2018-02-01  0
6   John    2018-06-01  4
7   John    2018-08-01  6
8   Ethan   2018-03-01  0
```

Comment: This only works if the date year is the same, but what if Anne had an entry for 2019-01-01? It doesn't work.

Comment: And yes! The month in the 4th row is 3, not 2. Already corrected.

Comment: Please if you could just update your answer so that it computes the column right for dates with different years, that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Data,

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['Mark',
  'Anne',
  'Anne',
  'Anne',
  'Anne',
  'John',
  'John',
  'John',
  'Ethan'],
 'date': ['2018-01-01',
  '2018-01-01',
  '2018-02-01',
  '2018-04-01',
  '2018-09-01',
  '2018-02-01',
  '2018-06-01',
  '2018-08-01',
  '2018-03-01']}
)
```

To calculate the difference in month, we could convert datetime to period ('M'), period difference has an attribute called `n` which returns numeric numbers,

```
df.assign(date = lambda x:pd.to_datetime(x['date']).dt.to_period('M'),
          months = lambda x:x.groupby('name')['date'].apply(lambda x:x.sub(x.iloc[0])).apply(lambda x:x.n))
```

Comment: @HRDSL what's your pandas version?

Comment: I dont know, I guess same as python: 3.7

Comment: `pandas` version, please check if it is the latest (0.25)

Comment: Yes it is the latest

Comment: Wrong number of items passed 4, placement implies 1 and some others before that one, for example: KeyError: 'months'.

Comment: @HRDSL Reproducible data provided.

Comment: I don’t know why it doesn’t work. What pandas version am I supposed to have so that it works?

Comment: please use pd.show_versions() to confirm if it is 25